# Is it logical to put both same-page links for rel="alternate" and rel="canonical" links?

Tags: html

- Google uses `<link rel="canonical" ... >` [to figure out the main page & how to best index a website](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/consolidate-duplicate-urls#reasons-to-specify-a-canonical-url) (so it may benefit SEO),
- Google [suggests adding a valid hreflang](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/seo/hreflang/) with a `<link rel="alternate" ... >` tag

I have only "main" pages in english. Does it makes sense to seth those links tags together ?

```
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com/current_page" />
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/current_page" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it makes sense, setting those link tags together can help improve your website's SEO and visibility in search results.